# Understanding COM Objects and how to declare them

Tags: c#, winapi, com, attributes

Say I want to create the interface for [IMMDeviceEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371399(v=vs.85).aspx).

I see examples online showing the definition:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{

}
```

**What I understand (maybe):** The `[ComImport]` Attribute specifies that it's from a dll. The `[Guid]` attribute is the interface identifier.

**What I don't understand:** How was this GUID value obtained? What does the `[InterfaceType]` attribute do? How do I fill in the rest of the functions?

I'm so lost trying to figure this stuff out, all the documentation is super opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How was this GUID value obtained?

The GUID is created as part of the COM interface definition; since you're trying to call someone else's object - you need to use their GUID. You can find it in the [mmdeviceapi.h](https://github.com/EddieRingle/portaudio/blob/master/src/hostapi/wasapi/mingw-include/mmdeviceapi.h) the [MMDevice docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx) point to.

> Header file Mmdeviceapi.h defines the interfaces in the MMDevice API.

```
 MIDL_INTERFACE("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")
    IMMDeviceEnumerator : public IUnknown
```

The normal way to do this is to add a reference to the COM dll or run tlbimp.exe which will generate a COM Class Wrapper for you with all the magic goo.

If a COM type library isn't available, though - then you basically have to do it yourself by going through the IDL file.

Like p/invoke signatures, this can get pretty painful - so [best to use an existing one if you can](http://daisy-svn.cvsdude.com/urakawa-sdk/trunk/csharp/audio/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/Interfaces/IMMDeviceEnumerator.cs).

For the larger questions of COM interop, it basically requires learning a little bit of COM and being familiar with C#. The [general docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx) are [out there](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM), but usually if you're just trying to use a well known COM component you're best off using a [library](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) if you can.

Comment: This is correct. What I meant was if you are creating your own, you create your own Guid.

Comment: This helps a lot,. and thank you so much for directing me to that library!

Answer (score 0):

You create the GUID yourself. There are generators online if you don't want to assign one yourself.

All interface types should derive from `IUnknown`.

Update: here is a generator. https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx

They use the same one because `IMMDeviceEnumerator` has already been defined with that specific GUID. If you create your own interface, you will create your own GUID.

You derive off `IUnknown` because

"Within that constraint, your custom interface can support almost any method or parameter, including asynchronous methods. You can also generate a type library for your custom interfaces so that clients can access information about your object's methods at run time. "

Comment: Unlikely to be helpful for OP who seem to be looking for interop code for existing interface.